# Iteration in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

It's been a while since I have used VBA on Excel.

I want to alphabetize the contents of each column on the sheet.

This is what I have:

```
Range("A1").Select
    Range("A1:A19").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:A19")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range("B1").Select
End Sub
```

How can I make this into a for loop that keeps going as long as the range is active?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. This code assumes your data is laid out in some type of table format. Also, it assumes you want the entire column sorted (including blanks and such). If you want to make the range more specific or just set it with a hard reference adjust the code where I commented.

```
Sub sortRange()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim loopRange As Range, sortRange As Range

Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")

With wks

    'can change the range to be looped, but if you do, only include 1 row of the range
    Set loopRange = Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Rows(1))

    For Each cel In loopRange

        Set sortRange = Intersect(cel.EntireColumn, .UsedRange)

        With .Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=sortRange
            .SetRange sortRange
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With

    Next

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
Option Explicit

Sub sample()
    Dim i As Long

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        For i = 1 To .UsedRange.Columns.Count
            .Columns(i).Sort Key1:=.Cells(1, i), Order1:=xlAscending, _
            Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
            Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 nice code. I was thinking of that, but when I was playing with in in my code, I was getting some issues with adding sortfields. I choose to clear them out then add them. Now I see, you don't even need that method!